# Common Lisp: This is not a number NIL and &rest parameters

Tags: common-lisp, cffi

On this line `((pointerp (first args)) (mem-aref (%vector-float-to-c-array (first args)) :float (second args)))` in the below code the `(second args)` compiles with the warning `This is not a number NIL`. The function works but how do I get rid of this warning in an implimentation independent way using just Lisp.  The solution would need to be really fast. The code took a long time to get to right and runs great so I can't really change the operation of it. the functions you don't recognize don't really matter as far getting warning to go away...Thank you in advance for any help.

```
(defun vector-float (&rest args)
  (cond ((eq (first args) nil) (return-from vector-float (%vector-float)))
    ((listp (first args))
     (c-arr-to-vector-float (first args)))
    ((symbolp (cadr args)) (%vector-float-size (first args)))
    ((pointerp (first args)) (mem-aref (%vector-float-to-c-array (first args)) :float (second args)))
    (t nil)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `(second args)` is `NIL` then either `args` has no `second` or its `second` is `NIL`. However, the third argument to `mem-aref` must be a number since it is an index. Therein lies the problem.

If in your program `(second args)` is allowed to be `NIL` (or to not exist), then you'll have to test for that possibility and avoid passing `NIL` to `mem-aref` (maybe by leaving out that optional argument). If `(second args)` is *not* allowed to be `NIL`, then the bug is somewhere else in your program.

E.g. (untested),

```
(defun vector-float (&rest args)
    (cond
        ((null (first args))
            (return-from vector-float (%vector-float)))
        ((listp (first args))
            (c-arr-to-vector-float (first args)))
        ((symbolp (second args))
            (%vector-float-size (first args)))
        ((pointerp (first args))
            (if (null (second args))
                (mem-aref (%vector-float-to-c-array (first args)) :float)
                (mem-aref (%vector-float-to-c-array (first args)) :float (second args))))
        (t nil)))
```

Comment: (second args)  can be nil...can u help me with a solution, to squash that warning....thanks for joining in btw:)

Comment: Perhaps something like the above.

Comment: Great, that worked like a charm, great way to think outside of the box